# Why does Task.FromResult require explicit cast?

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library

I have the following program:

```
async Task Main()
{
    IList<int> myList = await TestAsync();
}

public Task<IList<int>> TestAsync()
{
    return Task.FromResult(new List<int>());
}
```

The compiler complains that it can't convert a `Task<List>` to a `Task<IList>` in the `TestAsync` method:

> CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type
> `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<int>>` to
> `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IList<int>>`

Why can't it figure out that my method returns a `Task` of `IList`?

Comment: `Task`s are invariant so a `Task<List<int>>` is not a `Task<IList<int>>`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Why can't it figure out that my method returns an Task of `IList<int>`?

Because it doesn't. In this call:

```
Task.FromResult(new List<int>());
```

... type inference makes that equivalent to:

```
Task.FromResult<List<int>>(new List<int>());
```

So your method is trying to return a `Task<List<int>>` - and that's not compatible with `Task<IList<int>>`.

To simplify the point about `Task<>`, let's use `string` and `object` instead, and take out type inference and async entirely. The following code does not compile, and indeed shouldn't:

```
Task<string> stringTask = Task.FromResult<string>("text");
Task<object> objectTask = stringTask; // Doesn't compile
```

`Task<T>` is *invariant* - there's no conversion from `Task<T1>` to `Task<T2>` just because there's a conversion from `T1` to `T2`.

You don't need an explicit cast though - you can just use the implicit conversion earlier:

```
public Task<IList<int>> TestAsync()
{
    // It's important that this variable is explicitly typed as IList<int>
    IList<int> result = new List<int>();
    return Task.FromResult(result);
}
```

This uses the implicit conversion from `List<int>` to `IList<int>` for the `result` variable, and then it calls `Task.FromResult<IList<int>>` using type inference.

An alternative is to keep the method as it was before, except you specify the type argument for `Task.FromResult`:

```
public Task<IList<int>> TestAsync()
{
    return Task.FromResult<IList<int>>(new List<int>());
}
```